# Python: convert Unicode hex code to string (len=1)

Tags: python

How can I convert hex code, e.g. "A0B0" (this means U+A0B0 char) to unciode char,
e.g. string of length 1?
I use Py3k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` with base 16 will turn that hex string into an integer. `chr` will turn that integer into a string of length 1. So, in total: `chr(int('A0B0', 16))`.